# Memory management of NSTimer -- does it need to be assigned to a variable?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-leaks, nstimer, foundation

Whenever I want to make a timer, I just do:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 
                                 target:self 
                               selector:@selector(someMethod) 
                               userInfo:nil 
                                repeats:NO];
```

rather than

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 
                                                  target:self 
                                                selector:@selector(someMethod) 
                                                userInfo:nil 
                                                 repeats:NO];
```

Is the first one a memory leak? What's the correct way to use them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have no memory problem in either snippet; you simply have to make a choice about your needs for interacting with the timer.

When you schedule a timer, the run loop retains it, and a reference to the timer is passed along when it fires and its selector -- e.g., `(void) doTimerThing: (NSTimer *)tim`<sup>1</sup> -- is used, so it isn't *strictly* necessary for you to put it into a variable and retain it yourself. Apple explains this pretty clearly in the ["Memory Management" section](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000807-SW6) of the Timer Programming Topics doc.

If, however, you might want to invalidate the timer *before* it fires (or in between fires for a repeating timer), you do need to have a reference to it. In that case, it is also a good idea to call `retain` on it. The `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:...` method returns an object that you do not own, and you should not make assumptions about the memory status of objects you don't own (including whether they are in an autorelease pool or not, or how long the run loop is going to keep the timer around). If you need the timer (or any object) to stick around, you should make a claim of ownership on it by calling `retain`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that a timer's method should always [have one parameter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000807-SW1); the selector in your snippet looks like it is for a method that does not. The timer seems to work that way, but you're operating contrary to the documented interface.

Comment: What do you mean should always have one parameter?

Comment: Look at the snippet I included and read the linked doc. The timer's method needs to be able to take one argument, an instance of `NSTimer`.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to previous answers, if you don't need repeating timer, you can use

```
[self performSelector:@selector(someMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
```

instead of creating timer manually.

Comment: Are there any advantages to this or not really?

Comment: @mohabitar: This creates a timer behind the scenes, and it is a more straightforward, perhaps more readable, way to delay execution of a method for a period of time.

Answer (score 3):

In either way, there is no memory leak. The second solution is just affecting the result to a variable, whereas the first one don't store the result, but the effect are the same.

As the naming convention suggests, given the name `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:...` of the method, you know that it will returns an autoreleased object *(or to be more precise, it will return an object which you are not the owner, and for which you won't have to send a release to by yourself)*

You don't have to hold a reference to the created `NSTimer` if not needed: the timer will be scheduled on the RunLoop (and that's the RunLoop that will retain it until it is used, and release it when done, so you don't have to bother), so it will live by itself.

**But** if you don't store the returned `NSTimer` in a variable like in your second code, you won't be able to cancel the timer if you ever wanted to. Especially, if you setup a repeating timer, you will need to store it in a variable so that you can access it later, especially to send it an `invalidate` message so it can be cancelled.

Comment: `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:` does _not_ return an autoreleased object; it returns an object that is not owned by the caller.

Comment: Yeah sure but if you read my edit, I explained (as well as in the other comment) what I really mean and gave all the precisions about what I mean (and if you read carefully I already explained even before my edit that the RunLoop retaines the timer)

Comment: An object which is in an autorelease pool can still be owned by other objects, and an object which is not owned by the caller does not have to be in an autorelease pool. They are _not_ the same thing, and they should not be conflated.

Comment: More to the point, whether an object has ever been autoreleased is not worth thinking about outside of Instruments's history for the object. The only important question is, do you own it?